# How to remove white spots of standing water on the marble tiles?

Tags: cleaning, house-cleaning

I've tried a lot of time to clean marble tiles in my home but the tiles didn't get cleaned. How to remove white spots of standing water on the marble tiles?

Comment: Could you please explain what you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Take some acid and some quantity of detergent mix it in one glass of water and throw it directly to white spots on marble after 15 minutes rub  the surface of tiles with any brush, all spots will vanish it's my personal experience but in this process you should have to avoid your skin from acid.

Comment: You shouldn't use acid on marble. Acids corrode marble and cause stains or even holes.

Answer (score 1):

There are special, acid-free marble cleaners. Any household supply store should have it.

You can also use fine, stainless steel wool. Rub over the *dry* (!) stone with a dry stainless steel wool pad. The lime stains will be pulverized to a light dust that you can blow away or wash off with water. But be careful not to use non-stainless steel wool, as the abraded steel particles will rust and the rust will stain the marble.

---

If you have tried acid on marble, such as vinegar, citric acid, or other acidic cleaners, the stains you see may actually be the results of the acids destroying the polished marble surface. In that case, you need to polish it.

Answer (score -1):

You can pour vinegar on that water spots leave it for few minutes and remove it with cotton.or you can also use lemon use to remove these spots.
you can also use some detergent, the process is you will take some water in the pot and add some detergent in the water, take small piece of cloth and dip in that water and then rub on the surface of tiles where spots are present.

Comment: Pouring vinegar on marble? Definitely not recommend!